# Removing parts of a field in SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I have a question that I need help with :

1. I also need to extract the last two digits of the year and put in a text box using an expression. for eg, since we are in 2022, I need to extract the last two digits (22).
   grateful if someone can please help as I have not done this before and my syntax might be off

I have tried :

=DatePart(Year())-2

thank you

Comment: The usual way to do this is to convert the year to text and then take the last two digits with `RIGHT(<YEAR>, 2)`.

Comment: thanks, will be helpful if you could send the full block of code..thanks

Comment: `=RIGHT(YEAR(Today()), 2)` will give you the last two digits of the current year based on the system date/time.

Comment: Thanks Alan, I tried but it gave a syntax error in Today ()